# Switch(String) for Android with jdk 1.8

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, switch-statement

I want to use a switch statement using Strings in Android Studio (version 3.2.1), this should compile because I am using a java version of 1.7 or higher (1.8). 
Nevertheless it still doesn't work. It gives: 
*Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'byte, char, short or int'*

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's clear, that's a problem with compiler settings in IDE.

Confirm once that you are using java 7 or higher.

[image]

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the accepted answer to the dupe I flagged.